# How to rename the primary key field in CFWHEELS?

Tags: coldfusion, primary-key, cfwheels

This is what I've tried... but for some reason "model("user").primaryKey() is still returning the old "User_Id" column...

```
<cfset table("user_table")>
<cfset property(name="id", column="User_Id") />
<cfset setPrimaryKey(property="id") />
```

**UPDATE**
The problem lies within the "Scaffold" plugin.
It's using the "COLUMNLIST" instead of the "PROPERTYLIST"

I've repaired this and it seems to be generating properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally the question did not state that it was a problem with the Scaffold plugin.
However, the solution is to just specify

```
<cfset property(name="id", column="User_Id") />
```

(as stated in the CFWHEELS documentation)

The bug itself, lies within the Scaffold plugin which uses "COLUMNLIST" to generate the HTML.
The HTML is then referencing "#users.user_id#" which doesn't exist since it's now called "id".

I changed the Scaffold plugin to use "PROPERTYLIST" and now it's fine.

Very sorry for confusion!

Answer (score -2):

Try to put only

```
<cfset setPrimaryKey("id") />
```

inside User model. After all add `&reload=true` to your URL. This will rebuild the application and refresh the settings.

Comment: I don't think that makes sense... The actual tables column is "User_id"